# How to retain text between RegEx matches?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to extract some tags from string and perform some operations according to them, but the remaining string should retain with stripped tags and go for further processing.

Is it possible to do this in one run?

For example, if I have a code, which is taking tags:

```
var match, result = [], regex = /<oob>(.*?)<\/oob>/ig;
while (match = regex.exec(str)) {
    result.push( match[1] );
}
```

Can I take what between matches simultaneously?

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: What kinda "tags", are you parsing HTML with regex ?

Comment: We need the actual regex code....

Comment: How *exactly* do you want to "consume" this information?

Comment: A couple of magic tricks with `regex.lastIndex` could help. But you could just use a `string#split` with a regex pattern enclosed into a capturing group. No need to do everything in 1 step.

Comment: @seahorsepip see an update and you will have it

Comment: @Amit the content of matches I will pass to another JS function, while the retained part I will put to an input field

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
str.split(regex).forEach(function(str) {
   var match = str.match(regex);
   if (!match) {
       // between matches
   }
});
```

regex will need to have whole thing in parenthesis so the text that match will be in splitted array.